# Nifi : Json to CSv converter in NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

I am new to NIFI and this is my first task in it . I am trying to convert a JSON to CSV but I am not getting any CSV file generated . Attached is the method I followed. Please let me know where I am missing the logic.
My sample Json :
{"creation_Date": "2018-08-19", "Hour_of_day": 7, "log_count": 2136}

[image: Flow]

[image: Json Path reader config]

[image: CsvRecordSetWriter]

[image: Put File]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the right processors your schema definition is wrong.

The convertrecord proc should have a JsonTreeReader (with Schema Access Strategy : Infer Schema - the rest is default) and a CSVRecordSetWriter (Inherit Records Schema).

Play with the parameters in CSVRecordSetWriter to make you csv look the way you want.

**Input**

```
{"creation_Date": "2018-08-19", "Hour_of_day": 7, "log_count": 2136}
```

**Output**

creation_Date,Hour_of_day,log_count
2018-08-19,7,2136

**This is the conf for JsonTreeReader**
[image]
**This is the config for your CSVRecordSetWriter**

[image]

If you don`t want to use schema you will have to use a mix of :

```
EvaluateJson >> AttributestoCSV
```

Comment: Thanks for reply . But if I want to convert only 2 data fields (creation_Date and log_count) to csv how can I go it with out using schema. Please let me know.

Comment: but you should be more inclined to user RecordSet* controlers - jsonsplit + evaljson puts all flows in JVM - not very good for performance